# How to fix Tomcat failed to start in localhost?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Dynamic WebApp project, which people can visit and upload a file, but the problem is that whenever I build my project I get Tomcat v9.0 error saying:

```
'Starting Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
Details: Server Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

Console error:

```
Sep 07, 2016 9:39:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-30012"]
Sep 07, 2016 9:39:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-30013"]
Sep 07, 2016 9:39:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Sep 07, 2016 9:39:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-30012"]
Sep 07, 2016 9:39:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-30013"]
```

My Servlet script:

```
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
 import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

 @WebServlet("/propicuploader")
 public class ProPicUploader extends HttpServlet {
 private boolean isMultipart;
   private String filePath;
   private int maxFileSize = 50 * 1024;
   private int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024;
   private File file ;

   public void init( ){
      // Get the file location where it would be stored.
      filePath = 
             getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload"); 
   }
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
               HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {
      // Check that we have a file upload request
      isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
      if( !isMultipart ){
         out.println("<html>");
         out.println("<head>");
         out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
         out.println("</body>");
         out.println("</html>");
         return;
      }
      DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
      // maximum size that will be stored in memory
      factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
      // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
      factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

      // Create a new file upload handler
      ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
      // maximum file size to be uploaded.
      upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );

      try{ 
      // Parse the request to get file items.
      List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

      // Process the uploaded file items
      Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      while ( i.hasNext () ) 
      {
         FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
         if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
         {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            String fileName = fi.getName();
            String contentType = fi.getContentType();
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }else{
               file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
            }
            fi.write( file ) ;
            out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + fileName + "<br>");
         }
      }
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
   }catch(Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
   }
   }
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                       HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        throw new ServletException("GET method used with " +
                getClass( ).getName( )+": POST method required.");
   } 
 }
```

If I remove the code inside `doPost()` the Tomcat starts fine

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"      version="3.1">
  <display-name>Duck</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <context-param> 
<description>Location to store uploaded file</description> 
<param-name>file-upload</param-name> 
<param-value>
     E:\
 </param-value> 
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

FYI: I checked if any other app is using my Tomcat port which is 30012 with cmd: `netstat -a -n -o | findstr 0.0:30012` and I've got nothing as long as Tomcat haven't started in my IDE.

Comment: No one should embed markup in a streamed response from a servlet.

Comment: Have you considered checking the log files?

Comment: Tomcat is probably listening on port 8080.

Comment: no it is using port 30012, cause I have changed it so, and you said log aye , here is the last text contents `
2016-09-06 22:28:41 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
`

Comment: and the thing is that why does it works fine when i remove the code inside my `doPost()`